# How can I prevent a Schlumbergera from dropping buds?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, cactus

I recently bought a [Schlumbergera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlumbergera) from a reputable garden centre. It had buds on it when I bought it. It soon flowered and within a couple of weeks the flowers have all fallen off and the remaining unopened buds have also fallen off.

I have read online that this can be because of temperature changes / over watering. I also understand that for a Schlumbergera to flower successfully it has to go through a cycle of watering / not watering / inside / outside etc.

My initial thoughts are that because it has been grown and therefore the buds have developed in a different environment to what it is in now, the change of moving it into my house has caused the flowers and buds to drop, in which case, what could I do to prevent this from happening next year, and having to get a flowering Schlumbergera?

Answer (score 2):

You're right, Schlumbergeras are very sensitive to condition inconsistencies. Even rotating the plant can cause bud/flower drop. If you bring it into bud next year, it will have adapted to the conditions, and you shouldn't run into trouble if you give the plant good care and keep the growing conditions consistent.

You could buy a flowering one each year, but I think it's worth it to put the effort into one plant, and watching it grow over the years.

Answer (score 2):

All and any plants that goes from one environment (especially from a cool temperatured controlled garden center to a hotter home) to another suffers shock. Put the plant in the coolest part of your home, put in a larger container to allow roots room to grow and thrive and water only 2 times per week. Put plant in direct sunlight in days.